# Random post permalink

Tags: posts, permalinks

I want to make a random permalink for each new post. For example when an author creates a new post, he gets this kind of permalink automatically: http://mysite.com/x5Kvy6 (like bit.ly). 
But I want to have the option to choose a keyword instead of the random key.

Someone know the way or maybe a plugin to make this?

P.S.: I didn't research an url shortener plugin.

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I built a similar feature for my personal website, that consists of a new database table, WordPress admin page and some .htaccess rewrites. Unfortunately the setup is too involved with my particular installation to be useful as a plugin, but there are plenty of URL shortener plugins available already.

A quick search yields [this WP plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/short-link-maker/) but I've never tried it. You might need to try several plugins out, but I'm sure there is one available that can provide approximately the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Yes i have tested lots of url shortener for wordpress but they don t fit to my need, they just creat another permalink who refer to the post's permalink.

Comment: What are some of your specific requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I used the following plugin lately:
https://github.com/kasparsd/numeric-shortlinks
it normally create post ID based shortlinks, like `http://domain.com/123`, but has an option for alpha-numeric shortlinks too, like the example in your question. The option can be activated like this: `add_filter( 'numeric_shortlinks_bijection', '__return_true' );`. Take a look at the github page for more information/documentation.